# Assigning a range of values to a macro

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I am trying to rename a list of variables using a `for` loop.

My code looks like this:

```
local x 99 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
local k  2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28
local n: word count `x'

forvalues i = 1 / `n' {
    local a : word `i' of `x'
    local b : word `i' of `k'
    rename v`b' num`a'
}
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to assign the range for the macro `k` without writing it manually. Note that the delta between two values is not one.

Comment: You have not closed the previous thread you started. Accepting an answer would give you some reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you just want original suffixes 2(2)28, so doubling 1(1)14 suffices. Otherwise `help tokenize`.

```
local x 99 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
tokenize "`x'"
local n: word count `x'
forvalues i = 1/`n' {
    local I = 2 * `i' 
    rename v`I' num``i'' 
}
```

Other arithmetic progressions are as easy. For example, 3(2)... is

```
    local I = 2 * `i' + 1
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't close the last question. I did look in to tokenize. but I cant figure our how I would do this if the delta or the starting value is different. For example what should I do if I want values 3,5,7.. in my macro. Thanks